# How do I insert items via parameter into a Steam trade offer link?

Tags: http, url, steam, steam-web-api

I've seen that if you add the parameter "for_items[]" to the url "https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=58001078&token=jeCI_XHm&for_items[]=730_2_33939923237" you can automatically add an item from the partner to the trade offer, but theres a way to automatically add items from my inventory in the trade offer? (via url parameter).